# How to continue a loop from within a function?

Tags: python, design-patterns

Consider the following

```
for i in range(100):
    if cond1:
        cleanup()
        continue
    if cond2:
        cleanup()
        continue
    if cond3:
        cleanup()
        continue
    ...

    do_work()
```

I was wondering if there is a way to write this construct in a more concise way, such that at least there won't be the `cleanup(); continue` duplicated fragment.

It is almost like I want a `goto` inside the cleanup to just go back to the top of the loop, or to push the `continue` into the cleanup function.

Is there a way to do something like that?

---

EDIT with a more elaborate example:

```
for i in range(100):
    if a == 1:
        cleanup()
        continue
    b = input()
    if a + b == 2:
        cleanup()
        continue
    c = input()
    if a + b + c:
        cleanup()
        continue
    ...

    do_work()
```

You will notice I want each condition to stop or continue iteration, which can't be done with `or`. Even if it can, this makes reading the code much simpler and linear.

Comment: Do you really want all conditions  to do the same thing? In which case why not combine the tests (or not have them at all?)

Comment: why not if cond1 or cond2 or... etc ?

Comment: @both, this is a dummy example. Think about a small difference before the cleanup. Also, it makes logical sense to separate to several ifs, and not a single huge one.

Comment: Could you edit your example to be more representative? It's better to update the question than add clarifications in the comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your conditions are simple, just do one `if cond1 or cond2 or cond3:` but I'm guessing that the actual code is more complex than that.

Assuming your conditions are complex and/or involved some preparations that require those clean ups, you can enclose them in a one-iteration for-loop that you break when no conditions are met. This will allow you to centralize the cleanup()/continue in an else: statement

```
for i in range(100):
    for preconditions in [1]:
        ...
        if cond1: continue
        ...
        if cond2: continue
        ...
        if cond3: continue            
        break                # final break when no conditions are met
    else:
        cleanup()
        continue

    do_work()
```

*Note that you could do something similar with a custom exception and enclosing the conditions in a try/except statement but that seemed a bit overkill so I didn't include it in the answer*

Answer (score 1):

No; you can only control the loop from directly in the loop. `cleanup` cannot assume it will be called from a loop, so indirect breaks and continues are not allowed.

At least for the code shown, you can combine the various `if` statements into one:

```
for i in range(100):
    if cond1 or cond2 or cond3:
        cleanup()
        continue
    do_work()
```

Otherwise, you need to examine the return value of `cleanup` to determine whether to continue the loop or not.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `continue`? It seems like an `else` would work fine in this case.

Comment: The effect is the same if the `if` statement is the only thing in the body of the `for` loop, but I would still prefer `continue` to emphasize that *nothing* else in the body should run this iteration, as well as to avoid unnecessary indentation.